# Display Javascript links in a table

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi there I am trying to display my links in a table.  The links are getting pulled from a JSON data source and I want to just display the brand names in the td tags.  The goal would be to have:

```
<table border="1" colspan="5">

 <tr><td>Nike</td><td>Puma</td><td>etc</td><td>etc</td><td></td><td></td></tr>

</table>
```

I also need the rows to increase as the list of links will grow!

Here is a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/volterony/5nW86/

Volterony

Comment: Have you considered using a templating library??

Comment: Also `colspan=` is not a valid attribute for a table. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp

Comment: Unfortunately I am restricted to pure JS

Comment: do you use `jquery` ?

Comment: No.  Unfortunately I need to stick to JS as the lead developer doesn't want JQuery

Comment: @Volterony can I ask for what reason? Ultimately every library is using pure / vanilla javascript and some of the micro templating libraries are super light weight. http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to make things a lot simpler than what you have in your current fiddle. There's a lot going on and you don't need to be doing so much when you're just making HTML. I have amended your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5nW86/10/) and you can see I build the HTML dynamically.

```
  var company, link, html = "<tr>", cols = 4, currentCol = 1;

  for (company in brand) // Loop through each item in the array
  {
      if (currentCol > cols) { // Make sure we only have 4 columns
          currentCol = 1; // Reset the current column if we go over that
          html += "</tr><tr>"; // Stop the previous row and start a new one
      }
      html += "<td>" + company + "</td>";  // Add the current item to the table 
      currentCol++; // Increment the column count for the next loop
  }

  html += "</tr>";

  document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = html; // Append the html with our dynamically created html
```

Now the basics are done you should be able to add in any missing parts to the base template I provided (such as adding in anchor links, etc). Sometimes using the `document` API can be a bit daunting and overkill when you can write the HTML yourself.

Comment: Hi Deif Thanks for providing the example.  I will try and incorporate the links within your base template.  I am just a Javascript Newbie so I'll see how I get on

Comment: Deif I have tried to add the links but they dont seem to be loading the brand content?  http://jsfiddle.net/volterony/5nW86/

Comment: Your fiddle hasn't incorporated anything that I suggested. Please try and write some HTML.